# How to use intel openvino toolkit in google colab?

Tags: intel, google-colaboratory, openvino

Due to unfortunate reason of cpu, CPU dont support avx instruction and so Openvino toolkit not working in my machine.

I have model in my drive , 
How can i use the openvino run convert the model in IR using google colab.

Answer (score 1):

I will just put commands here, might explain lines later. I have set up openvino 2019 R3 version with google colab, steps are as follows:

1. `!sudo apt-get install pciutils`
2. `!sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y cpio`
3. `!lscpu`
4. `!cat /etc/os-release`
5. `!wget http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/16057/l_openvino_toolkit_p_2019.3.376.tgz`
6. `!tar -xvzf l_openvino_toolkit_p_2019.3.376.tgz`
7. `!cd l_openvino_toolkit_p_2019.3.376/ && bash install.sh`
8. `!source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh`
9. `!/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites /install_prerequisites.sh`
10. `!source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh && \    /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/demo/demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can try some example Google Colab notebook like this one: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xla23daYYbTIfbdHF0nyHzHyoAvVtyaG). Better to post more specific questions on Stack Overflow regarding how to install as opposed to say asking like an open question.

But if I were you, I would use the official information as a reference since Google Colab runs on a Linux-based hosted machine: [Official documentation](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html).

Comment: saying error , how can i sove it,
/bin/bash: /opt/intel/openvino/install_dependencies/install_openvino_dependencies.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites/install_prerequisites.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Try uncommenting the line which says `# !wget http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/16057/l_openvino_tool`... Otherwise it won't download. So change it to `!wget http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/16057/l_openvino_tool` and try again.

Comment: Also uncomment out some of the lines with a single `#` in front... The author didn't want to re-run these commands so they are commented out

Comment: Hi K.S how is openvino scholarship going :)

Comment: HI @god it is going okay so far

Answer (score 0):

This package seems to be a good way to use openvino in google colab:
https://github.com/alihussainia/openvino-colab

```
!pip install openvino-colab

import openvino_colab
```

And you are ready to use openvino at /opt/intel/openvino ...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the inference engine on colab. Also, it is possible to create xml and bin files from pretrained models.

Explained here: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/intel-openvino-on-google-colab-20ac8d2eede6